3d party connector development for XM Cloud
Some time ago, companies could deliver third-party connectors using the Sitecore Package. But now, the Sitecore Marketplace is no longer available, and as far as I know, XM Cloud does not support Sitecore Package installation.
GitHub was suggested as an alternative to Sitecore Marketplace, but this is not as convenient as the Sitecore Package installation.
I'm considering a NuGet package as a lightweight alternative for such purposes, but seems like there can be some challenges like item installation.
Are there any best practices so far for producing 3d party connectors for XM Cloud?

Sitecore XM Cloud is a SaaS application, so 3rd party integrations need to be approached very differently. While currently it is technically possibly to deploy customizations to the platform (CM), this is actively discouraged and is only available for scenarios where there are no other options. Deploying customizations can put you at risk for future updates, especially if there are breaking changes. Because of this, deploying Nuget packages would not be the right way to create a connector.
Sitecore Connect
When connecting XM Cloud to 3rd party applications, one option is Sitecore Connect (a white label of Workato. This is a low code system that allows you to configure recipes that pull data from one system, do something with it and push it to another and many other things. This could be an option when integrating with an existing application that has an API available
API First
If you want to provide some new functionality to XM Cloud, for example, language translation, you would need to build your application that does the work outside of XM Cloud. This could be created as another SaaS application or a codebase that a client can host themselves.
Your application can integrate with XM Cloud via webhooks and the Authoring and Management GraphQL API.
In the above example, you might use the Workflow webhooks to create a workflow command that submits some content to your application for translation. Once the content has been translated, then your application can write that data back to XM Cloud using the Authoring GraphQL API.
These are the patterns that should be followed when creating a connector or 3rd party functionality for XM Cloud.

Thanks Richard, I wondering if GraphQL can finally process complex queries without any limitations?
